# Underscore template doesn't work in debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

```js
// run with console open
//and paste following when you hit the debugger:

/*
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};

var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");

console.log(template({name: "Mustache"}))
*/
debugger
//should return:
//underscore-min.js:5Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

//out of debugger though, it works:
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");
console.log(template({name: "Mustache"}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

I can't run [underscore's sample template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) code while in a debugger (I want to play with actual data in the console).

1. code in .js file runs fine. ✓
2. pasted in console after page load runs fine. ✓
3. pasted in at time of debugger breakpoint - doesnt work. ✘

   ```
   _.templateSettings = {
       interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
   }

   var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");

   template({name: "Mustache"});
   ```

   Error:

   ```
   underscore.js:1461 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
   ```

edit:

---

Errors on `template({name: "Mustache"});`

[Line 1461](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/e4743ab712b8ab42ad4ccb48b155034d02394e4d/underscore.js#L1461) of Underscore version 1.8.3:

```
var template = function(data) {
  return render.call(this, data, _);
};
```

Comment: Which version of underscore? Which line in the pasted code triggers the error? What's on line 1461 of the version of underscore.js you're using?

Comment: Answered (see edit)

Comment: Where is the breakpoint? Is it inside underscore?

Comment: debugger; is just in my js own file where i'm trying to use underscore.

Comment: here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c2z8dtjq/1/

Comment: I fail to encounter any error with your code. I was able to hit the debugger using both approaches  `_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
debugger
var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");
console.log(template({name: "Mustache"}))` & also this ==> `debugger
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");
console.log(template({name: "Mustache"}))`

Comment: And both the times it stopped and printed the log `Hello Mustache`. Also FYI I ran this in `chrome`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a symptom of `Function` instantiation (underscore line 1454), and it can be recreated using the following statement:

```
new Function('return true;')
```

With any page open in the browser (even this one), copy this into the console and execute, it will print the following:

```
function anonymous() {
    return true;
}
```

However if the page is currently **Paused in debugger** the statement returns `undefined`. I tried running the same in Firefox, it doesn't work either, doesn't even return.

I can't explain the effect on the V8 (Chrome) or SpiderMonkey (Firefox) Javascript engines when they are paused in the debugger.

If you really need it, here's a workaround: https://jsfiddle.net/na4Lpt7L/

```
var source = "Hello {{ name }}!";
debugger;
var template = _.template(source);
debugger;
```

When the first breakpoint hits:

```
> source = "Goodbye {{ name }}!";
< "Goodbye {{ name }}!"
```

Now continue execution, and on the second breakpoint:

```
> template({name: "Mustache"});
< "Goodbye Mustache!"
```

If you want to try a few options I'd say stick it in a loop (`while (source.length) { ... }`)

Comment: Have you seen [video](https://vimeo.com/248018117) ? Password is Passsword [file](https://ufile.io/okxmk)  file here no debugger; break point or even console.log inside _.template do you know why